# Doubt about local flatness of low dimensional embeddings

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, surfaces, geometric-topology, curves

I would like to know if it is possible to have a simple curve $\gamma $ on a surface $S$ such that

- $\gamma$ is compact and embedded (i.e. with respect to the topology induced from $S$ it is homeomorphic to the closed interval $[0,1]$, or to $S^1$)
- $\gamma$ is not [locally flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_flatness) (i.e. $(S,\gamma)$ is not locally homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ or to $(\mathbb{R}^2,[0,+\infty[)$ as topological pair )

Notice that here $\gamma$ is not assumed to be a smooth submanifold; we only require it to be homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ or $S^1$ as a topological manifold (even if $S$ is equipped with a smooth structure). Since the easiest examples of non locally flat embeddings I know come from knots or knotted arcs in 3-dimensional space, I suspect the answer could be negative, but I am not really sure how to prove it. My guess is that having dimension 1 *and* codimension 1 should prevent wild behaviour.

Thanks in advance for any reference/suggestion/example.

Comment: Yes, this is true and is probably proven in Moise's book.

Comment: Ok this should follow from Thm 13 in chapter 10: if a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is abstractly triangulable, then there is a homeomorphism $f$ of the plane taking it to a polyhedron of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is of course locally flat. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Then write an answer to your own question in order to get it off the "unanswered" list.