# Are topological 1-manifolds embedded in 2-manifolds always locally flat?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I would like to know whether the following is true:

Let $M$ be a topological 2-manifold (without boundary), and let $i: [0,1] \to M$ be a continuous embedding. Then $\mathrm{Im}(i)$ is [locally flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_flatness) in $M$.

This question has been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895994/doubt-about-local-flatness-of-low-dimensional-embeddings), but I could not obtain the statement from the reference given in the comments.
As pointed out there, the counterexamples to local flatness that are commonly given take place one dimension higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you want does follow immediately from the theorem quoted in the second comment of [the link you provided](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895994/doubt-about-local-flatness-of-low-dimensional-embeddings):

- ... if a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is abstractly triangulable, then there is a homeomorphism $f$ of the plane taking it to a polyhedron of $\mathbb R^2$, which is of course locally flat.

Simply use that $i[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and hence abstractly triangulable.

Comment: Thank you!
This sounded tautological to me, but I think I was confused about the notion of a polyhedron:
When a polyhedron is defined as a collection of simplices _in_ $\mathbb{R}^2$, one does not mean that these are embedded arbitrarily, but that they need to retain their shape (so that all edges are straight)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct regarding polyhedra in $\mathbb R^2$. When one speaks of a simplex in $\mathbb R^n$ one is (generally) speaking about a "Euclidean" simplex, i.e. a 1-simplex is a line segment, a 2-simplex is a triangle, and so on.